# Authorization_IdentityNotFound Error in Microsoft Contoso Airlines Team Example

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am getting an `Authorization_IdentityNotFound` error when I try to run the [Microsoft Contoso Airlines Team Example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/contoso-airlines-teams-sample).

I registered my App at `apps.dev.microsoft.com`, added in all the Graph permissions (as well as Admin Consent) and added the `Web.config.secrets` file as described in the ReadMe.

Do I have to do something with an authentication token? I am using an Office 365 Developer Account.

Here are my permissions:

[image]

I am able to log in when running the app in Visual Studio, and I am able to get to the screen where you can select the airlines and crew members, but the error pops up when I click on 'Create Team'.

Here is the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Also, please try to refrain from using screenshots. They're notoriously challenging to grok and the inability to cut and paste so it can be easily replicated often results in people just skipping over your question.

Comment: I'd suggest using Fiddler to trace the calls so you can see exactly what it's sendcing in the `POST`. Of particular interest would be the payload (body) and the `Authorization` header.

Comment: there is a good thread here that troubleshoots that error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151346/authorization-identitynotfound-error-while-accessing-graph-api

Have you tried going into https://aad.portal.azure.com and doing admin consent from the portal there?
Can you debug into your application and see whether you get an access token or not? The only thing that calls the API in that sample is create team button. the other UI is hard coded.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? If so, please share the resolution. Thanks!