# Authenticate App Services backend using Microsoft Graph token?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, microsoft-graph-api, adal

Edit:

I have added the "id_token" but still get an "Unauthorized" response.
Here is my login code:

```
PublicClientApplication myApp = new PublicClientApplication("My-AppID-From-App-Registration-Portal");
string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await myApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes).ConfigureAwait(false);

JObject payload = new JObject();
payload["access_token"] = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
payload["id_token"] = authenticationResult.IdToken;

user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, payload);
```

Original Post:

Is it possible to authenticate to a App Services backend using the token retrieved from Microsoft Graph?
I have already tried using this token and calling LoginAsync() with AzureActiveDirectory as the provider, this doesn't work.

```
JObject payload = new JObject();
payload["access_token"] = GraphAuthenticationHelper.TokenForUser;
user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you want to use WindowsAzureActiveDirectory as the provider argument. Also, turn on application logging in the portal and you should be able to see a warning message with the reason for the unauthorized response. Can you share that information as well?

Comment: Ah ok, even if using a MSA account?
Either way, both don't work.

Under "LogFiles/DetailedErrors", I get the following info:
HTTP Error 401.83 - Unauthorized
Most likely causes:
The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.

Detailed Error Information:
Module
   EasyAuthModule_32bit
Notification
   BeginRequest
Handler
   ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code
   0x80004005
Requested URL
   https://myapp__9131:80/.auth/login/aad
Physical Path
   D:\home\site\wwwroot\.auth\login\aad

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. You need to look at *application* logs (Diagnostic Logs --> Application Logging (File System)). I think what you are looking at is web server logs.  BTW, this is a converged AAD endpoint that supports both AAD and MSA, right?

Comment: Yes it is indeed a "Converged" application and not a "Live SDK" application. I did enable Application Logging (File System), but don't even see a "Application Logs" folder when I FTP in.

Comment: If you repro the issue with logging enabled, you should definitely see the logs. When using the Kudu portal, they can be found under D:\home\LogFiles\Application\.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146289/discussion-between-chris-gillum-and-matt-f).

Answer (score 3):

*UPDATE: In my original answer, I said you cannot do this. But in reality, you can do this but it's a dangerous thing to do since anyone with a valid Microsoft Graph token could theoretically access your APIs. Before I walk you down that path, let me describe the "right" way to access the Microsoft Graph on behalf of your end user.*

The right way to do this is to use the on-behalf-of flow in the mobile backend code to exchange the user's ID token for a Microsoft Graph token.  The flow looks like the following:

1. Client initiates a login with AAD using MSAL and sets the resource to the mobile backend (not the Graph). The result should be a set of tokens.
2. Client uses the mobile SDK to do a login with BOTH the access_token AND the id_token from #1.

Example code:

```
JObject payload = new JObject();
payload["access_token"] = {access_token.from.msal};
payload["id_token"] = {id_token.from.msal};
var user = await MobileService.LoginAsync(
    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,
    payload);
```

3. The backend code exchanges the user's ID token (from the `x-ms-token-aad-id-token` request header) for a graph token. This token exchange is known as "on-behalf-of" and is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of). I *think* this can be done using ADAL or MSAL libraries, but I wasn't able to find documentation. It's also simple enough that you could implement the HTTP protocol directly without too much trouble.
4. The backend uses the newly acquired MS Graph token and makes the graph API call.

You can also cache the graph token that you acquire on the backend so that each API call doesn't require more AAD API calls to do token exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris.
So if I am passing the graph token along with my API calls, that means I'll have to authenticate the user twice, one for App Services, the other to get the Graph token. Is this correct?

Your solution that I linked in the above comment works perfect for AAD, I'm baffled why it's not as straight forward for a Microsoft Account. Especially since it's being touted as one endpoint for both MSA and AAD. WAs hoping to have one login for the user, for either MSA and AAD, which can be used to authenticate against App services, and also access the MS Graph.

Comment: You don't need to authenticate twice with my suggestion. Your backend will just accept the token as-is and use it to make API calls to the MS Graph API.

TBH, I was surprised that my linked solution worked for AAD w/v2 endpoints at all. In general, AAD is moving away from the "resource" model, which is why I'm not entirely surprised that it doesn't work for MSA accounts (MSA wasn't supported at all in AAD v1).

Comment: My apologies Chris, I don't understand.
Which client-flow should I use for MSA?
I've tried MSAL, but the token retrieved from it does not authenticate against App Services. I pass it as "access_token" in a JObject to the AzureMobileClient.LoginAsync() method. I get an Unauthorized response. All documentation points to using the Live SDK, which is on its way out. Should I use it anyway? Is it the only way?

Comment: It seems I can't even use the Live SDK for authentication, as my app is registered under "Converged Applications", rather than "Live SDK applications" in the apps.dev.microsoft.com registration portal. Even with the "Live SDK Support" checkbox active, I get a Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException: The app is not configured correctly to use Live Connect services. Just about ready to give up on accessing the Graph entirely.

Comment: Ah, let me update my answer. I think I may have misspoke earlier. You are right that the approach I mentioned requires two logins, which is not ideal. There is actually another way to make this work...

Comment: Thank you Chris! The "id_token" seems to be the missing piece to the puzzle. Don't have the chance to try it out at the moment but will first thing tomorrow morning. Question is though, will this work with MSA? Is the process the same? AAD works fine and well with your other solution, so the remaining roadblock is with MSA.

Comment: Hey Chris, it didn't seem to work, I updated my original question with further info and my code. I think the part I'm missing is "and sets the resource to the mobile backend (not the Graph)". Not sure if I'm doing that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think no ,please refer to document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameauthenticationaauthenticate-users

> > Replace INSERT-RESOURCE-ID-HERE with the client ID for your mobile app backend. You can obtain the client ID from the Advanced tab under Azure Active Directory Settings in the portal.

The audience of the access token should be the  client ID for your mobile app backend . So if resource is https://graph.microsoft.com/(`aud` claim in access token) , then Client-managed authentication won't work .

Comment: This documentation says "client flow is preferred", then proceeds to link the Live SDK, which I believed to be deprecated. The amount of mixed information in all of this documentation is really difficult to follow.

App Services is a Microsoft Service, as is the MSGraph API. I expected these two to work together elegantly.

Thanks to a post by Chris Gillum, I got this working with Azure AD accounts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010063/calling-microsoft-graph-api-from-inside-azure-functions/44013797#44013797

However, this does not work with Microsoft Accounts, any idea why?