# Connect Azure Function to Microsoft Graph as a Multi-tenant Application using Azure App Service Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I have been working a while trying to figure out how to connect an azure function to any users office 365 graph to query their inbox without any success.  I need help understanding the right approach to do the following:

When a users makes an http get request to the http triggered function it should:

1. Prompt the user to log into their Microsoft work account.
2. Request permission to access their inbox.
3. Query their inbox to get a count of unread messages.
4. Reply with the count of unread messages.

This should work for ANY users that call the function regardless of which azure active directory instance they are accessing.

Is this possible?

If so, can anyone explain how to configure the azure function to achieve this?

Thanks,
Stewart

Comment: I have setup azure app service authentication for the azure function to be a multi tenant application and to use express settings for authentication to azure active directory.  I can login as a user in the same tenant successfully.  I can also login as a user in a different tenant (I get the log in screen and even the consent screen).  However when the user in the other tenant gets redirected back to the app they get a 400 error with a message of Invalid Token ID.

Comment: Well now it has changed.  I am now getting this error:
Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 1903de88-83d8-4db7-bca9-46bf3322bd1e
Timestamp: 2017-06-23 17:04:36Z
AADSTS50020: User account 'stearm01@protiviti.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/16532572-d567-4d67-8727-f12f7bb6aed3/' does not exist in tenant 'ToCoCMS' and cannot access the application '3e7ca12a-ae7b-4c6e-98dd-1f9fa58c389b' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Microsoft Graph API from inside Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010063/calling-microsoft-graph-api-from-inside-azure-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this.  The proposed solution just returns the details of the user from the Microsoft Graph instead of the inbox count.

1. Create function and app.

   1. Create a new azure function app.
   2. Add a javascript web hook.
2. Create a Microsoft Application Registration [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList).

   1. Generate a new password in the application registration and save the password.
   2. Generate a Web platform and set the redirect url to https://.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback.
   3. Add any needed Delegated permissions (Mail.Read).
3. Setup Azure App Service Authentication for the Azure Function App.

   1. Turn on Authentication for the Azure Function App (Platform Features -> Authentication/Authorization).
   2. Set the "Action to take when request is not authenticated" to "Log in with Azure Active Directory".
   3. Set the Active Directory Authentication settings to 'Advanced'.

      1. Set the Client ID to the Application Id created in Step 3.
      2. Set the Client Secret to the password generated in Step 4.
      3. Leave the Issuer Url and Allowed Token Audiences blank.
4. Set the Azure Function Authorization Level to Anonymous (Click Function -> Integrate).
5. Add the following code to your function:

   ```
   var request = require('request');

   module.exports = function (context, req) {
       var parameters = {
           grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
           client_id: process.env.WEBSITE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
           client_secret: process.env.WEBSITE_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
           assertion: req.headers['x-ms-token-aad-id-token'],
           resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
           requested_token_use: 'on_behalf_of'
       };
       var tenant = req.headers['x-ms-client-principal-name'].replace(/.*@/, "");
       request.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+tenant+'/oauth2/token', {form: parameters}, function (aadErr, aadResponse, aadMsg) {
           var msgJson = JSON.parse(aadMsg);
           request.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/', {'auth': {'bearer': msgJson.access_token}}, function (err, response, msg) {
               context.res = {
                   body: msg
               };
               context.done();
           });
       });
   };
   ```
6. Add the 'request' npm package to your solution.

   1. Go to https://yourfunctionname.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/
   2. Add a package.json file to the wwwroot folder and add a dependency to request.
   3. Add the following to your package.json:

   {
       "name": "yourfunctionname",
       "version": "0.0.1",
       "dependencies": {
           "request": ">=2.81.0"
       }
   }

   3. Use the console (button on the left second from the bottom) and run:

   npm install
7. Test your function.

   1. Navigate to your function.
   2. You should be prompted to log in.
   3. Use any active directory account from any tenant.
   4. You should also be prompted to provide your consent.
   5. After that you should see the information about the user you logged in as from the Microsoft Graph served in the response.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the information you need on this other StackOverflow question: [Calling Microsoft Graph API from inside Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010063/calling-microsoft-graph-api-from-inside-azure-functions)

As for how to register an AAD multi-tenant application, you can find more information here: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-multi-tenant-authentication-azure-app-service-authentication-options/. The main trick is going to the Advanced tab and clearing the **Issuer URL** field..

Comment: This is close but doesn't cover a multi-tenant application.  I think I have it figured out but I am still working on verifying the Microsoft Graph access.  I have the authentication working.  The trick was to use Advanced mode on the authentication configuration for AAD and clear out the Issuer URL.

Comment: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-multi-tenant-authentication-azure-app-service-authentication-options/

Comment: Yep, that's the main difference. That blog post is also the one I often point people to.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm working through this issue now.  When fixed I'll post all steps I used to get this working.  When I call the function am prompted to grant permissions.  Some wire must be crossed somewhere or I don't have an app setting set right.   AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Comment: You need to have your tenant admin consent to using the multi-tenant app. One way to do this is to send them to https://{function-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad?prompt=admin_consent.  More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent

Comment: I don't think that is the issue.  My app only requests delegated permissions.  The user gets prompted for granting the delegated permissions.  I think this might be related to a problem in my code.  I used your response in the other thread.  I also tried providing admin level consent but that still gets the same issue.

Comment: Here is more detail... 
 https://gist.github.com/Stewartarmbrecht/0b11b5a3b8ccc5b2f5e3f4b715d5e25a