# using AD app registration in http request in an azure function

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am accessing azure API's (graph, inTune etc).
To do this I have created an App Registration with permissions against the azure API's.

I now want to encapsulate the call within an azure function.
To call a REST API from an azure function, I understand I need to use a HTTP Request.

But I cannot identify how to use the existing App Registration to authenticate against the API's.

Can anyone advise how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

**Few of the workarounds I used to call the Azure GRAPH API from the existing Azure Function App Registration activated the authentication with Microsoft Account in the AAD is:**

**Approach 1:**

- Initialized the Http Client to call the Azure Graph API.

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);
            var me = await client.GetStringAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(me, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
```

- To obtain the graph token, go to graph.microsoft.io and Click on Graph Explorer > Click on Access Token to get the token value.

[image]

Run the Http Trigger Function to send the Http Request to the Azure Graph API:

**Result when running locally: **
[image]
[image]

Above approach is the token passed manually in the code which is not the good approach in the Cloud (Azure)

**Approach 2:**

In order to pass the bearer/access token in the Request Headers to Http Client Request for querying the Graph API in the Cloud (Azure - Azure Functions):

**Http Trigger Function:**

```cs
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Http; 
using System.Net.Http.Headers; 

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string graphToken, TraceWriter log)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);
    return await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
}
```

To query the Graph API on behalf of the user making the request, add the below snippet to the `function.json`:

```cs
{
   "type": "token",
   "direction": "in",
   "name": "graphToken",
   "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
   "identity": "userFromRequest"
}
```

Also, you can run the function with the `ClientCredentials` authentication mode as it runs as an application instead of in the context of a particular user.

**References:**

1. [Microsoft Documentation of Azure Functions with Microsoft Graph API Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/azure-functions).
2. [Calling Microsoft Graph API from inside Azure Functions - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44010063)